# Using JSF EL in a plain HTML attribute

Tags: html, jsf, attributes, el, managed-bean

Can we use JSF EL inside a HTML tag? For example, inside a plain HTML `<td>` element, can we use EL `#{bean.color}` for the `bgcolor` attribute?

```
<td bgcolor="#{bean.color}">
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer depends on the JSF version and the view technology used. The technical term you're looking for is "using EL in template text" (i.e. not inside any tag/component).

As per your question history you're using JSF 1.2 on Websphere. I assume that you're still using old JSP, the predecesor of Facelets. Whether JSF EL `#{}` works in template text depends on the JSP version used. JSP version goes hand in hand with Servlet version.

When your container supports Servlet 2.5 and the `web.xml` is declared conform Servlet 2.5, then you're using JSP 2.1. In that case, you can just use `#{bean}` in JSP. The JSF EL `#{}` was namely moved from JSF 1.1 to JSP 2.1 under the name "unified EL".

```
<td bgcolor="#{bean.color}">
```

However, when your container supports at most Servlet 2.4, then you're basically using JSP 2.0 and you have to use `${bean}` instead.

```
<td bgcolor="${bean.color}">
```

This has only one prerequirement: in the same document, somewhere **before** the above line where you reference the JSF bean by `${bean}`, you need to ensure that you've *already* referenced the very same bean by `#{bean}` in a JSF tag beforehand, otherwise the bean won't be precreated.

When you're using the JSP's successor [Facelets](http://facelets.java.net/nonav/docs/dev/docbook.html), even though in a Servlet 2.4 environment, then you can just use

```
<td bgcolor="#{bean.color}">
```

#### See also:

- [Difference between JSP EL, JSF EL and Unified EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812755/difference-between-jsp-el-jsf-el-and-unified-el) - A bit of history of EL
- [Is it suggested to use h:outputText for everything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539894/is-it-suggested-to-use-houtputtext-for-everything)
- [PWC6228: #{...} not allowed in a template text body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213620/pwc6228-not-allowed-in-a-template-text-body/)

---

**Unrelated** to the problem, the `bgcolor` attribute is **deprecated** in HTML. You should be using CSS `style` attribute instead.

```
<td style="background: #{bean.color}">
```

Even then, the above is considered poor practice. Put CSS in a `.css` stylesheet file which you include via `<link>`/`<h:outputStylesheet>` and use sensible classnames (e.g. `.odd`, `.even`, `.success`, `.cancelled`, etc) and render a CSS style class instead. For example, if the color depends on some status:

```
<td class="#{bean.status}">
```

Comment: You're welcome. In the future questions please take care that you mention the exact JSF impl/version used (e.g. "Mojarra 1.2_15") and the view technology used (e.g. JSP or Facelets) and preferably also the servletcontainer make/version used.

Answer (score 2):

You can integrate el with html in facelets.

example:

```
   <td style="background: #{bean.color};"><br /></td>
```

example 2:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location = '#{bean.url}';
</script>
```

Comment: As per the question history, OP seems to be using JSF 1.2 on legacy JSP.

Comment: Yeah. Cosmin's answer is more complete and will get my vote. I've updated to be a bit more clear.

Comment: Actually, whether it works depends on JSP version. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If you're using Facelets as ViewHandler, yes. If you're using JSP, HTML must be in `<f:verbatim>` tag.

Comment: Putting HTML in `<f:verbatim>` is only necessary for JSF 1.0/1.1. In JSF 1.2 that's not necessary anymore. As per the question history, OP is using JSF 1.2.

Comment: Uh, just by experience :) No kidding, the view handler has been changed in JSF 1.2. Even more, that tag is deprecated in JSF 2.0. You may find this an interesting read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623911/what-are-the-main-disadvantages-of-java-server-faces-2-0/3646940#3646940