# Generate dynamic meta tags for Facebook in JSF

Tags: facebook, jsf, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

How can I generate dynamic meta tags for facebook on server side? Depending upon the data fetched from database, I need to dynamically set the value of og:title, og:description etc.

Can I use HttpServletResponse.addHeaders() to do that? If yes then how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JSF, you can just use EL in template text.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="#{bean.og.title}" />
<meta property="og:description" content="#{bean.og.description}" />
<meta property="og:url" content="#{bean.og.url}" />
...
```

Bean and model can be prepared and used the usual way here.

#### See also:

- [Using JSF EL in a plain HTML attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283310/using-jsf-el-in-a-plain-html-attribute/)