# Add <sup>&#174;</sup> to <h:outputText>

Tags: html, jsf, jsf-2

I want to add HTML `<sup>&#174;</sup>` (which is <sup>®</sup>) to `<h:outputText>`, but I get exception.

```
<h:outputText value="&lt;<sup &#174;/>&gt;" escape="false" />
```

What is incorrect?

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: Remove the "<" and ">" (which are &lt; and &gt; respectively)

Comment: Are you using JSF 1.0/1.1 or what? The whole `<h:outputText>` seems totally useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `<` an `>` signs in xhtml code. Shouldn't your value be something like this:

```
<h:outputText value="&lt;sup&gt;&#174;&lt;sup/&gt;" escape="false"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `<h:outputText>` at all. You can just write down HTML plain vanilla in a JSF page.

E.g.

```
<p>#{bean.productName}<sup>&#174;</sup></p>
```

#### See also:

- [Is it suggested to use h:outputText for everything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539894/is-it-suggested-to-use-houtputtext-for-everything/5540859#5540859)