# Why am I getting h:outputLabel as an unknown tag?

Tags: jsf, facelets

I'm trying to learn JSF for a project I have in my internship, and I'm really struggling.

Can anyone explain why in this piece of code I am getting an "Unknown tag" warning for h:outputLabel?

Thank you!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0      Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h:outputLabel value ="Welcome #{loginbean.name}"></h:outputLabel>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you forgot to declare the `h:` XML namespace.

Add that XML namespace to your `<html>` element.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
```

#### See also:

- [Our JSF wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) - contains a Hello World

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the `<h:outputLabel>` generates a HTML `<label>` element, with the intent to label HTML input elements. You seem to want to display some text only. In that case you are actually using the wrong element and you should be using `<h:outputText>`.

```
<h:outputText value="Welcome #{loginbean.name}" />
```

Or even better, just use EL in template text. This was not supported in JSF 1.x, but this is supported in JSF 2.x on Facelets.

```html
Welcome #{loginbean.name}
```

#### See also:

- [Is it suggested to use h:outputText for everything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539894/is-it-suggested-to-use-houtputtext-for-everything/5540859#5540859)

Comment: Can you explain, why it´s better to use it in template text, without the h:outputText? Does it really save time, because it´s not in the jsf-tree?

Comment: @marcel: it will end up in tree, but with less overhead and better maintainability.

Comment: That was fast! Thank-you :)