# Format a JSF converted value

Tags: jsf, converters

Today I noticed **ocpsoft** has a nice [time library](http://ocpsoft.org/prettytime/) adapted to use in **JSF 2** as a converter. The strong point of that is you can use the converter directly in the date displayed in the view and it converts it into a string telling the user something like `6 hours ago` or `17 hours from now`. I think my best is to combine both, the JSF converted date and this one to display something like `26-03-2013 17:00 (4 hours from now)`. I can achieve something similar with the following code:

```
<h:outputText value="#{task._StartDate}" style="padding:2px;">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm" timeZone="GMT+1" />
</h:outputText>
<h:outputText value="#{task._StartDate}">
    <f:converter converterId="org.ocpsoft.PrettyTimeConverter" />
</h:outputText>
```

My problem comes when I want to put the second value into parenthesis. The `PrettyTimeConverter` accepts only a date as a value and I can't write the parenthesis there directly. Also JSF is not accepting the following:

```
<h:outputFormat value="({0})">
    <f:param value="#{task._StartDate}">
        <f:converter converterId="org.ocpsoft.PrettyTimeConverter" />
    </f:param>
</h:outputFormat>
```

With that I have the following error:

```
<f:converter> Parent not an instance of ValueHolder: 
javax.faces.component.UIParameter@1492636
```

Any idea about how to achieve that avoiding writing both parentheses using specific `h:outputText` tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just put those parentheses directly in template text without the need for another `<h:outputText>`s.

```
<h:outputText value="#{task._StartDate}" style="padding:2px;">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm" timeZone="GMT+1" />
</h:outputText>
(<h:outputText value="#{task._StartDate}">
    <f:converter converterId="org.ocpsoft.PrettyTimeConverter" />
</h:outputText>)
```

#### See also:

- [Is it suggested to use h:outputText for everything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539894/is-it-suggested-to-use-houtputtext-for-everything/5540859#5540859)