# Trying to find c:out tag from the JSTL library within JSF application

Tags: jsf-2, jstl, el

I am building out a dynamic table using JSTL and was hoping to make use of the c:out tag to help build out some expressions, but am not able to find that tag available among the other JSTL core tags.

I have the following namespace being used:

```
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
```

and made sure my web.xml file was set to use the 2.5 spec found here 
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info

but still only find  catch, choose, forEach, if, otherwise, set, and when.

Additionally, I tried importing the JSTL 1.2.1.jar libraries as well with no success.

So, should the c:out tag be available for me to use in JSF2 ?  If so, what steps am I missing?

Regards,

Mike

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `<c:out>` indeed not available in [JSF2 Facelets](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/). You don't need it in JSF2 Facelets anyway. Just use the JSF equivalent `<h:outputText>`,

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.text}" />
```

or even better, just put EL in template text,

```
#{bean.text}
```

It will already be implicitly XML-escaped if that's your sole concern (and was during old JSP2 ages actually the sole reason why `<c:out>` is been used; in JSP1 the tag was simply mandatory in order to display a bean property as EL in template text wasn't supported in JSP1). The `<c:out>` offers no additional advantages over those standard JSF2 Facelets ways, that's why it's been removed from the JSTL subset for Facelets.

#### See also:

- [Is it suggested to use h:outputText for everything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539894/is-it-suggested-to-use-houtputtext-for-everything/5540859#5540859)

Comment: if people do need to render the HTML within the variable in the same way c:out escapeXml="false" is used, then use escape="false". I came across this thread when I got Tag Library supports ... but no tag was defined for name: out