# php echo equivalent in JSF

Tags: html, jsf-2, javabeans, facelets

I would like to know if there is a php echo equivalent in JSF. I would like to publish html from my bean to my facelet.

This is because I want to add three different primefaces components each time a user clicks on one of the component that has been added. I could not achieve this with taglibs.

Thank you

Comment: There is not need any echo version of jsf. Just put #{some string variable in some context} or ${some string variable in some context}

Comment: the problem with using strings is that the html is not transformes. EX: <p:selectOneMenu... is going to be dispayed as is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you got confused by builtin XSS prevention of JSF which caused your "plain vanilla" HTML to get escaped and thus displayed as-is instead of being interpreted as part of HTML source. Given that you're familiar with PHP, the explanation is that JSF has basically PHP's [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) by default turned on in all EL expressions printing output.

Just use `<h:outputText>` with `escape` attribute set to `false` to turn off implicit HTML escaping.

```html
<h:outputText value="#{bean.html}" escape="false" />
```

Please make sure that you're fully aware of the potential XSS attack hole created here when it concerns user-controlled input. Your question at its own already indicates that you had no idea of it.

#### See also:

- [CSRF, XSS and SQL Injection attack prevention in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722159/csrf-xss-and-sql-injection-attack-prevention-in-jsf/7725675#7725675)
- [Is it suggested to use h:outputText for everything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539894/is-it-suggested-to-use-houtputtext-for-everything/5540859#5540859)

---

As to the concrete functional requirement,

> *This is because I want to add three different primefaces components each time a user clicks on one of the component that has been added. I could not achieve this with taglibs.*

Please note that JSF code is not HTML code. You should instead be writing those JSF components directly in the view and use the `rendered` attribute to render them conditionally.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, the problem with using rendered is that I do not know in advance how many components there will be. Each segment that is added contains a component c. Each time the user clicks on the component, another segment is loaded.