# Converter for entity in h:outputText

Tags: jsf, converters, el

We have an entity `MyType`:

```
MyType { String s; getS();}
```

And we have a JSF converter `MyTypeConverter` for this type:

```
@FacesConverter(forClass=MyType.class)
MyTypeConverter { 
    public String getAsString() { return ((MyType)o).getS().toUpperCase();}
}
```

And we have a backing bean `MyBean`:

```
MyBean { 
    getMyType() { return new MyType("hallo");}
}
```

And we have a view `my.xhtml`:

```
<h:outputText value="#{myBean.myType}"/>
```

The above view works fine:

> HALLO

When I edit it as follows:

```
<h:outputText value="(#{myBean.myType})"/>
```

I expected to see:

```
(HALLO)
```

However, the result is:

```
(org.playground.model.MyType@cb4a479)
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

When you have a converter with a `forClass` it gets called if the value is of the specified type. `myBean.myType` is obviously of type `MyType` but `(#{myBean.myType})` which evaluates to `#{'('.concat(myBean.myType.toString()).concat(')')` is of type `String`, so the converter will not and can not be applied on the given value.

I think your intention was, that the converter will be used whenever a EL expression evaluates to a value of type `MyType`. But it will only be applied as if you would specify it by `<f:converter converterId="myTypeConverter"/>` on some ui-controls. This would not work either if the given `value`-property is of an invalid type.

To resolve this you would either have to override the `toString`-method on `MyType`, to call the converter explicitly in the EL or to define another method on `MyType` which you call explicitly in the EL and which returns the String you would like to see.

Answer (score 1):

The converter applies to the **entire** component's value. In your case,

```html
<h:outputText value="(#{myBean.myType})"/>
```

this is evaluated as `String` because of the parentheses.

Just put the parentheses outside.

```html
(<h:outputText value="#{myBean.myType}"/>)
```

#### See also:

- [Is it suggested to use h:outputText for everything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539894/is-it-suggested-to-use-houtputtext-for-everything/)