# How to select one of many Resource Bundles

Tags: jsf, resourcebundle

Currently my project has three resource bundles in my `faces-config.xml` as follows:

```
<resource-bundle>
  <base-name>com.example.text.common</base-name>
<var>common</var>
</resource-bundle>
<resource-bundle>
  <base-name>com.example.text.option1</base-name>
  <var>option1</var>
</resource-bundle>
<resource-bundle>
  <base-name>com.example.text.option2</base-name>
  <var>option2</var>
</resource-bundle>
```

I need to use two resource bundles, the common bundle will always be used and is hard coded in the view pages of my site. However, I wish to only use one of the two option bundles, either `option1` or `option2`. Is there a way to specify which of the two option bundles to use based on a condition. The desired outcome is that is this case:

```
<h:outputText value="#{oneOfTheOptions['contact.explanation']}"/>
```

the `oneOfTheOptions` would be dynamically set to one of the appropriate bundle name. Is there a mechanism in JSF that can accomplish this ? If not, is any other way to dynamically set the Resource Bundle for view components ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are stored as request attributes (like request scoped managed beans). So, you should be able to obtain them via the request scope map `#{requestScope}` using a dynamic key in brace notation `#{map[key]}`.

Imagine that the EL variable `#{bundleKey}` can hold one of the string values `"common"`, `"option1"` or `"option2"`, then this should do:

```
#{requestScope[bundleKey]['contact.explanation']}
```

It can even be a bean property:

```
#{requestScope[bean.bundleKey]['contact.explanation']}
```

Note that you don't need a whole `<h:outputText>` around it, provided that you're using JSF2/Facelets. See also [Is it suggested to use h:outputText for everything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539894/is-it-suggested-to-use-houtputtext-for-everything)