# Have a output text as a part of command button

Tags: html, jsf, commandbutton

I want to insert **outputText** in the value attribute of a **commandButton**. The problem I am facing here is that the 'value' attribute of the commandButton only takes static text as value but I want this text to change according to the value assigned to that list and the whole value should be displayed inside the commandbutton.

```
<h:commandButton id="submit-button" styleClass="click_button1"
                                type="submit" value="Yes"
                                action="#{xyz.deleteAction(o)}" update="msgs" />
```

In this, instead of "yes", I want something like this

```
Yes, I want this thing <h:outputText size="15" value="#{o.name}" /></b> from <h:outputText size="15" value="#{o.detals}" /></b>
```

as the value.

Comment: Uhhhmmm you can do EL in the value attribute without a problem. Also string concatenation. It nowhere states you can only do static text

Comment: The `<h:outputText>` doesn't have a `size` attribute and those `</b>` tags are invalid and confusing. Ultimately, you can just use EL in value attribute too like so `value="blah #{o.name} blah"`. Is this what you're actually looking for? I've seen that many starters are unaware of "partial" EL expressions in JSF component attributes and/or that they think that `<h:outputText>` is the only way to print an EL expression (which is an indication that wrong learning resources are being used to learn JSF).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you really need** some `h:outputText` features such as `escape="false"` then your best bet is to use `h:commandLink` instead. You may need to tweak your CSS if you want to get a look and feel close to `h:commandButton`.

```
<h:commandLink id="submit-button" styleClass="click_button1" action="#{xyz.deleteAction(o)}" update="msgs">
     Yes, I want this thing <h:outputText value="#{o.name}" /> from <h:outputText value="#{o.detals}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

**If you only need** to display some dynamic values then you can perfectly use an EL expression

```
<h:commandButton id="submit-button" styleClass="click_button1" type="submit" value="Yes, I want this thing #{o.name} from #{o.detals}" action="#{xyz.deleteAction(o)}" update="msgs" />
```

See also [Is it suggested to use h:outputText for everything?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5540859/2118909)

**Notes:**

- I removed the `</b>` tags from your example as this looks like a typo from me.
- As BalusC stated in his comment, `h:outputText` [doesn't](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/outputText.html) have a `size` attribute.

*Edited following Kukeltje and BalusC's comments.*

Comment: You mean escape=“false“ you mean as (afaik) the value is by default escaped (but I could be wrong)