# h:outputText need style for particular text

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces 5.1. In my student I need style particular style in particular text.Below code I try It will show error(The value of attribute "value" must not contain the '<' character). So I replace < to &< and &&gt for > that time I faces error(The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference)

```
<p:outputPanel>
<h:outputText styleClass="noWrap" escape="false" 
value="#{common.ConfirmMessage1} <b style='color:red'>'
#{student.numberOfUserFound}'</b>"/>
</p:outputPanel>
```

My doubt is separate text is solution or any other way?

Comment: Just use second `h:outputText` and give it css class with bold, red font by `styleClass` attribute. `<h:outputText styleClass="noWrap" escape="false" 
value="#{common.ConfirmMessage1}"/> <h:outputText styleClass="boldRedStyle" value="#{student.numberOfUserFound}"/>`

Comment: @Geinmachi same outputtext set style is  possible?

Answer (score 2):

Just don't use `<h:outputText>`. It has no technical necessity in this specific case.

```
<p:outputPanel>
    <span class="noWrap">
        #{common.ConfirmMessage1}
        <b style='color:red'>'#{student.numberOfUserFound}'</b>
    </span>
</p:outputPanel>
```

#### See also:

- [Is it suggested to use h:outputText for everything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539894/is-it-suggested-to-use-houtputtext-for-everything)

---

That being said, I suggest to take a step back from JSF and start learning some [basic HTML](http://htmldog.com/guides/html/) first. JSF will then be easier to understand. In the context of this question, JSF is just a HTML code generator.

Comment: @Karthik: please accept answers if they were helpful. That is how stackoverflow works.