# Composite Component inside ui:repeat: How to correctly save component state

Tags: jsf

I have a custom component that implements `UIInput` and that needs to save some state info for later reuse in postback requests. Used standalone it works fine, but inside an `<ui:repeat>` the postback finds the saved state of the latest rendered row of data. The log output of an action call is

```
INFORMATION: myData is "third foo"
INFORMATION: myData is "third foo"
INFORMATION: myData is "third foo"
INFORMATION: ok action
```

where I would expect

```
INFORMATION: myData is "first foo"
INFORMATION: myData is "second foo"
INFORMATION: myData is "third foo"
INFORMATION: ok action
```

I understand that `myComponent` is a single instance inside of `ui:repeat`. So what is the best way to save component state so it is restored correctly for each row in the dataset?

My XHTML form:

```
<h:form>
    <ui:repeat var="s" value="#{myController.data}">
        <my:myComponent data="#{s}"/>
    </ui:repeat>

    <h:commandButton action="#{myController.okAction}" value="ok">
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form"/>
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

My Bean:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class MyController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2916212210553809L;

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MyController.class.getName());

    public List<String> getData() {
        return Arrays.asList("first","second","third");
    }

    public void okAction() {
        LOG.info("ok action");
    }
}
```

Composite component XHTML code:

```
<ui:component xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:cc="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite">

  <cc:interface componentType="myComponent">
    <cc:attribute name="data"/>
  </cc:interface>

  <cc:implementation>
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
      <h:outputLabel value="cc.attrs.data"/>
      <h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.data}"/>
      <h:outputLabel value="cc.myData"/>
      <h:outputText value="#{cc.myData}"/>
    </h:panelGrid>
  </cc:implementation>
</ui:component>
```

Composite Component backing class:

```
@FacesComponent
public class MyComponent extends UIInput implements NamingContainer {

    private static final Logger LOG=Logger.getLogger(MyComponent.class.getName());

    public String calculateData() {
        return String.format("%s foo", this.getAttributes().get("data") );
    }

    public String getMyData() {
        return (String)getStateHelper().get("MYDATA");
    }

    public void setMyData( String data ) {
        getStateHelper().put("MYDATA", data);
    }

    @Override
    public String getFamily() {
        return UINamingContainer.COMPONENT_FAMILY;
    }

    @Override
    public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context) throws IOException {
        this.setMyData( calculateData() );
        super.encodeBegin(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void processDecodes(FacesContext context) {
        super.processDecodes(context);
        LOG.log(Level.INFO, "myData {0}", getMyData() );
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what "the correct way" is, I can think of some workarounds: 1) use `"MYDATA" + getClientId()` as state key **or** 2) use `getAttributes()` instead of `getStateHelper()` **or** 3) use `c:forEach` instead of `ui:repeat` (which results in totally different component tree as Kukeltje would note here ;p) but (3) does not help when using your component within dataTable.

Comment: Thanks @Selaron, but Im really looking for the "correct way" in this particular case. `c:forEach` and `getAttributes` is no workaround in our case, using `getClientId()` is a nice workaround. But, really, this is a bit ugly, isnt it?

Comment: Yes it's ugly. I'm excited to see this answered either as I had to work around this up to now.

Comment: The approach is strange and confusing. My first try would be to use `getStateHelper()` instead of `this.getAttributes()` because `getStateHelper()` will be aware of the iterating context.

Comment: @BalusC Well, the behaviour of `getStateHelper()` is my problem. Here we have two requests. In the first one the component gets encoded and we put `myData` into the `stateHelper` using `encodeBegin`. In the second request, a postback, the component gets decoded. And in `processDecodes` the `stateHelper` presents us unexpected data. Thats my question: How to use the `stateHelper` the proper way such that it is aware of the iterator even in a postback request? From my expectation it should do so out of the box - but it doesnt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just tried reproducing your issue and yes, now I get what you're after all. You just wanted to use the JSF component state as some sort of view scope for the calculated variables. I can understand that. The observed behavior is indeed unexpected.

In a nutshell, this is explained in this blog of Leonardo Uribe (MyFaces committer): [JSF component state per row for datatables](http://lu4242.blogspot.com/2011/06/jsf-component-state-per-row-for.html).

> The reason behind this behavior is tags like `h:dataTable` or `ui:repeat` only save properties related with `EditableValueHolder` interface (`value`, `submittedValue`, `localValueSet`, `valid`). So, a common hack found to make it work correctly is extend your component from `UIInput` or use `EditableValueHolder` interface, and store the state you want to preserve per row inside "`value`" field.
>
> [...]
>
> Since JSF 2.1, `UIData` implementation has a new property called `rowStatePreserved`. Right now this property does not appear on facelets taglib documentation for `h:dataTable`, but on the javadoc for `UIData` there is. So the fix is very simple, just add `rowStatePreserved="true"` in your `h:dataTable` tag:

In the end, you have basically 3 options:

1. **Use `UIInput#value` instead of something custom like `MYDATA`**

   As instructed by the abovementioned blog, just replace `getMyData()` and `setMyData()` by the existing `getValue()` and `setValue()` methods from `UIInput`. Your composite component already extends from it.

   ```
   @Override
   public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context) throws IOException {
       this.setValue(calculateData()); // setValue instead of setMyData
       super.encodeBegin(context);
   }

   @Override
   public void processDecodes(FacesContext context) {
       super.processDecodes(context);
       LOG.log(Level.INFO, "myData {0}", getValue() ); // getValue instead of getMyData
   }
   ```

   And equivalently in the XHTML implementation (by the way, [the `<h:outputText>` is unnecessary here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539894/is-it-suggested-to-use-houtputtext-for-everything)):

   ```
   <h:outputText value="#{cc.value}" /> <!-- cc.value instead of cc.myData -->
   ```

   However, this didn't really work when I tried it on Mojarra 2.3.14. It turns out that Mojarra's implementation of the `<ui:repeat>` indeed restores the `EditableValueHolder` state during [restore view](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/blob/master/impl/src/main/java/com/sun/faces/facelets/component/UIRepeat.java#L420) (yay!), but then completely clears out it during [decode](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/blob/master/impl/src/main/java/com/sun/faces/facelets/component/UIRepeat.java#L818) (huh?), turning this a bit useless. I'm frankly not sure why it is doing that. I have also found in Mojarra's `UIRepeat` source code that it [doesn't do that](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/blob/master/impl/src/main/java/com/sun/faces/facelets/component/UIRepeat.java#L440) when it's [nested](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/blob/master/impl/src/main/java/com/sun/faces/facelets/component/UIRepeat.java#L455) in another `UIData` or `UIRepeat`. So the following little trick of putting it in another `UIRepeat` attempting to iterate over an empty string made it work:

   ```
   <ui:repeat value="#{''}">
       <ui:repeat value="#{myController.data}" var="s">
           <my:myComponent data="#{s}" />
       </ui:repeat>
   </ui:repeat>
   ```

   Remarkably is that nothing of this all worked in MyFaces 2.3.6. I haven't debugged it any further.

   ---
2. **Replace `<ui:repeat>` by `<h:dataTable rowStatePreserved="true">`**

   As hinted in the abovementioned blog, this is indeed [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIData.html#setRowStatePreserved-boolean-) in `UIData` javadoc. Just replace `<ui:repeat>` by `<h:dataTable>` and explicitly set its `rowStatePreserved` attribute to `true`. You can just keep using your `MYDATA` attribute in the state.

   ```
   <h:dataTable value="#{myController.data}" var="s" rowStatePreserved="true">
       <h:column><my:myComponent data="#{s}" /></h:column>
   </h:dataTable>
   ```

   This worked for me in both Mojarra 2.3.14 and MyFaces 2.3.6.
   This is unfortunately not supported on `UIRepeat`. So you'll have to live with a potentially unnecessary HTML `<table>` markup generated by the `<h:dataTable>`. It was during JSF 2.3 work however [discussed](https://download.oracle.com/javaee-archive/javaserverfaces-spec-public.java.net/jsr372-experts/2015/03/0447.html) once to add the functionality to `UIRepeat`, but unfortunately nothing was done before JSF 2.3 release.

   ---
3. **Include `getClientId()` in state key**

   As suggested by [Selaron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/865107/selaron) in your question's [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59046877/composite-component-inside-uirepeat-how-to-correctly-save-component-state/59221095#comment104337543_59046877), store the client ID along as key in the state.

   ```
   public String getMyData() {
       return (String) getStateHelper().get("MYDATA." + getClientId());
   }

   public void setMyData(String data) {
       getStateHelper().put("MYDATA." + getClientId(), data);
   }
   ```

   Whilst it's a relatively trivial change, it's awkward. This does not infer portability at all. You'd have to hesitate and think twice every time you implement a new (composite) component property which should be saved in JSF state. You'd really expect JSF to automatically take care of this.

Comment: What about an `o:repeat` Primefaces did it once too for exactly thus reason iirc... might even be a solution too. I can give it a try... not sure though if it can be done implementation independent

Comment: Hu, it feels more like a bug than a feature. Anyway thanks a lot for your efforts! Btw, do you know of some ongoing discussion of that issue for jsf 2.4? I think `rowStatePreserved` for `ui:repeat` is a must have.

Comment: I just gave `p:repeat` a try: It doesnt preserve rowstate either.

Comment: @kukeltje nope; p:repeat is just a fork of Mojarras ui:repeat, to provide bugfixes for PRO Users, which are still on old Mojarra versions on old application servers.