# JSF Add prefix to output text in datatable

Tags: jsf

I'm following the below example.

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/basic.xhtml

I would like to add prefix to the data table. How to add it?

Current Output

```
Id          Year    Brand   Color
1c859c99    1985    Honda   Maroon
37143be3    1993    Ford    Red
4cd0ff68    1985    Volvo   Black
8f12cce2    1963    Audi    White
```

Expected Output

```
Id          Year      Brand     Color
1c859c99    1985    Car Honda   Maroon
37143be3    1993    Car Ford    Red
4cd0ff68    1985    Car Volvo   Black
8f12cce2    1963    Car Audi    White
```

---

```
 <p:dataTable var="car" value="#{dtBasicView.cars}">
 <p:column headerText="Id">
    <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
 </p:column>

 <p:column headerText="Brand">
    <h:outputText value="#{car.brand}" />
 </p:column>

 </p:dataTable>
```

---

```
 <p:column headerText="Brand">
    <h:outputText Car?? value="#{car.brand}" />
 </p:column>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take your pick.

```
<p:column headerText="Brand">
    <h:outputText value="Car #{car.brand}" />
</p:column>
```

```
<p:column headerText="Brand">
    Car <h:outputText value="#{car.brand}" />
</p:column>
```

```
<p:column headerText="Brand">
    <h:outputText value="Car" /> <h:outputText value="#{car.brand}" />
</p:column>
```

```
<p:column headerText="Brand">
    <h:outputText value="Car" /> #{car.brand}
</p:column>
```

```
<p:column headerText="Brand">
    Car #{car.brand}
</p:column>
```

They are all equally fine.

#### See also:

- [Is it suggested to use h:outputText for everything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539894/is-it-suggested-to-use-houtputtext-for-everything)